# Unable to set hsva/hsla attribute of pygame.Color

Tags: python, python-3.x, colors, pygame

As one can read in the pygame documentation [here](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/color.html#pygame.Color.hsva), a `pygame.Color` object has two different attributes, namely `pygame.Color.hsva` and `pygame.Color.hsla` that can be read and assigned to.

However, I seem to be unable to do this. In fact, running the script

```
import pygame
from pygame import Color as C
pygame.init()

t = (100, 0, 0, 100)

c = C(0,0,0)
print(c.hsva)
c.hsva = t
print(c.hsva)
c = C(100, 45, 10)
print(c.hsva)
c.hsva = t
print(c.hsva)
```

prints unexpected results, namely

```
(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 100.0)
(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 100.0)
(23.333333333333336, 89.99999999999999, 39.21568627450981, 100.0)
(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 100.0)
```

Which clearly shows I am not being able to assign to the `.hsva` attribute (changing "hsva" to "hsla" shows the same erratic behaviour). Furthermore, after defining a new color and trying to change the `.hsva` the color changes completely.

Am I missing something or is this a bug?

Comment: The pygame.color object stores the color value internally as RGB from what I can tell. So if the saturation and value are both 0, hue won't affect the RGB values at all - they'll be all zeros. So, when you ask it for the hsva representation of its RGB values, the hue could be anything, and it seems the default is zero. But the question is, why do you care what the hue is if the saturation and value are zero?

Comment: @RandomDavis I thought changing the hue would change the colour all by itself, regardless of saturation and value. So maybe my only problem was that I wasn't fully aware of how the colour schemes work.

Comment: Right. A hue of anything, but a saturation and value of zero, would be represented in RGB as (0, 0, 0). Changing the hue, thus, wouldn't affect the RGB whatsoever. But this is just assuming it only stores the color internally as RGB, which seems to be the case.

Comment: @RandomDavis As it turns out, changing saturation and value allow me to change the hue altogether. Should I delete the question?

Comment: You can self-answer if you want, no need to delete a question that others might find useful in the future.

Answer (score 5):

To make it easier for others to take quickly something useful from visiting this question in the future let me summarize in an answer the outcome of the discussion:

> The in the question provided code does not show a bug in Pygame nor does it show any unexpected behavior.

To understand that the `.hsva get/set` worked as expected it is necessary to be fully aware of how the colour schemes work in Pygame, not making the error of thinking that changing the hue would change the colour all by itself, regardless of saturation and value.

> **The pygame.color object stores the color value internally as RGB**.

So if the saturation and value are both 0, hue won't affect the 
RGB values at all - they will be all zeros. So, when you ask it 
for the hsva representation of its RGB values, 
the hue could be anything, and it seems the default is zero.

A hue of anything, but a saturation and value of zero, would be represented 
in RGB as (0, 0, 0). Changing the hue, thus, would not affect the RGB whatsoever.